# Ho do I remove separator from table view updated with search results with empty rows?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using the same table view for data as well searching and filtering to show some data. However I want it show blank separator when I get empty rows. I am right now getting something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXqrw.png)

Yes I have grown through some related questions already. But they solve the problem when there is a static table view. In my cases I am showing search results in the same table view and I want to remove separator only with search results.

Comment: `self.tblVW.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)` write this line to remove separator for empty rows.

Comment: *"I want to remove separator only with search results"* - then only set the table view's `footerView` while showing search results.

Comment: What about adding the footer view after searching...?

Comment: You can do one thing after your filter if array is empty append one empty string to array

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this kind of situation is to remove the separator altogether from the table view and add your own to the cell when you want it to. I use something like this

```
func returnSeparator() -> UIView{
        let screenFrame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let viewFrame = CGRect(x: 18, y: 140, width: screenFrame.width - 36, height: 0.5)
        let viewR = UIView(frame: viewFrame)
        viewR.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.2)
        return viewR
    }
```

And then in cellForRowAt:

```
cell.addSubview(returnSeparator())
```

This way you can control which rows will have a separator and which won't. You can even modify the separator's appearance this way.

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this problem is to remove default seperator from tableview. Select separator style none like given in the picture.

[image]

Then add UIView of height(around 1 units) of a single line at bottom.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

If you are not using custom cell , then follow the given code below.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (dataSource.count != 0) {
        [tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
    }else{
        [tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use grouped tableView style , its awesome in UI also 
I personally love that !